# CodeBlocks не компилирует код с функциями для строк

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, после установки Code Blocks решил протестировать несколько программок и наткнулся на то, что он не хочет нормально работать со строками. На такой программе выдает ошибку `error: 'to_string' was not declared in this scope`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    string a_str = to_string(a);
    cout << a_str;
}
```

Что не так?

Comment: ошибки скините или угадывать будем?)

Comment: Галочку "Использовать стандарт С++11" поставили?

Comment: error: 'to_string' was not declared in this scope|

Comment: @Platun0v просто компилятору нужно указать что нужно включить C++11 стандарт, например в GCC компиляторе он указывается через `g++ -std=c++11`. В CodeBlocks наверняка это нужно указать в свойствах проекта где-то.

Comment: Нет, все указано в настройках

Comment: Версия и тип компилятора?

Comment: @Platun0v либо компилятор старый и не поддерживает С++11 либо может настройки не делают что нужно, попробуйте найти в настройках проекта полную строку командную для вызова компилятора, и в этой строке найдите есть ли включение С++11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `to_string` появилась в стандартной библиотеке С++11, поэтому вам нужно использовать компилятор, который поддерживает эту версию стандарта.

Скорее всего, вы используете CodeBlocks под windows с устаревшей версией MinGW и чтобы решить проблему, вам надо установить компилятор актуальной версии, с поддержкой указанного стандарта.

Советую поставить [MinGW-w64](https://mingw-w64.org) (форк и продолжатель MinGW) крайней версии (проще всего это сделать через [on-line установщик](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/latest/download)).

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало)

Comment: @Platun0v Тогда отметьте ответ как решение.